# Route attribute always returns null in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

This:

```
dump($route = $request->get('_route'));
```

or this:

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route') }}
```

returns null in whichever page am in.

Comment: is a sub-request or a master request?

Comment: which version of symfony you are using?

Comment: uh! that's  it. this is a sub-request, a template rendered from another template.